# Plot maps in python error : no arguments in initialization list

Tags: python, visualization, folium, choropleth, pandas-bokeh

From the following files I want to do a map plot by using folium:

Polygons file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uhj7OyHktPseR_CtRD0vPfq8HziHA4RK/view?
Postcode variable level: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oFBITKzqLyTvQEASmZmO6CGCOzdPacgH/view?

#### Attempt1 (folium):

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import folium

df_postcode_variable = pd.read_csv("postcode_sample.csv", dtype=str)  # Postcode variable level
df_postcode_variable['people'] = df_postcode_variable['people'].astype(float)
df_polygons = gpd.read_file("postcode_polygons.shp") # Polygons file
df_polygons.crs = "EPSG:4326"

my_map = folium.Map(location=[41.3890727,2.1572654], zoom_start=13,
                   detect_retina=True, control_scale=False)

folium.Choropleth(
        geo_data=df_polygons,
        name='choropleth',
        data=df_postcode_variable,
        columns=['cp','people'],
        key_on='cp',
        fill_color='OrRd',
        fill_opacity=0.5,
        line_opacity=0.8,
        line_color='Blue',
        legend_name='number of people'
    ).add_to(my_map)

my_map
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: key_on `'cp'` not found in GeoJSON.
```

#### Attempt 2(pandas_bokeh) working:

```
import pandas_bokeh
pandas_bokeh.output_notebook()

df_joined=df_polygons.merge(df_postcode_variable.set_index('cp'), on='cp')

df_joined.plot_bokeh(simplify_shapes=20000,
                  category="people", 
                  colormap="Spectral", 
                  hovertool_columns=["cp","people"])
```

[image]

How could I fix this error on folium? cp is in both objects so, It doesnt make sense to me. It seems that is not thetecting `cp` in `df_polygons`.

Comment: Please note that `pandas_bokeh` is a separate project, maintained by people who are not on the Bokeh core team. I have updated the post/tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the geodata is in geopandas format, the key is specified as `feature.properties.column_name`, as in geojson. See this for [details](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/GeoJSON_and_choropleth.ipynb).

```
my_map = folium.Map(location=[41.3890727,2.1572654], zoom_start=12,
                   detect_retina=True, control_scale=False)

folium.Choropleth(
        geo_data=df_polygons,
        name='choropleth',
        data=df_postcode_variable,
        columns=['cp','people'],
        key_on='feature.properties.cp',
        fill_color='OrRd',
        fill_opacity=0.5,
        line_opacity=0.8,
        line_color='Blue',
        legend_name='number of people'
    ).add_to(my_map)

my_map
```

[image]

Comment: great!, it was a simle thing but no very intuitive. I know it is another question but, Any insight on why pandas_bokeh is plotting the poygons badly?

Comment: If you feel that the color visualization you are setting is too weak, you can choose a different color map. Or you can create your own. For more information. [See this](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/Colormaps.ipynb), I haven't used Bokeh, but from my research it seems that `simplify_shapes` allows you to determine geo layers in meters. I haven't tried it, but a smaller value might make the polygons more accurate. I got the basis from [here](https://github.com/PatrikHlobil/Pandas-Bokeh).

Answer (score 0):

This error message hints at an unexpected data type in your data which is causing `np.isnan` to complain somewhere under the hood, probably `string`.

Try changing the data type of your `people` column to `int`:

```
df_postcode_variable['people'] = df_postcode_variable['people'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Hello rvd, you have provided some example data to check that the solution works, in your answer, you suggest a conversion to int, but it is to float that works directly.
Still the error prevails, the problem is not solved, so this is more a comment than an answer.